# How get logs for direct requests for jpg images in NGINX?

Tags: nginx, jpeg, access-log

I want direct requests for jpg images files to be logged in access.log.
For example, someone directly accesses the image saved in my wordpress:

https://www. my domain /wp-content/uploads/2021/07/image.jpg

How can I see it in the log record? **I have removed access_log off** and it stays like this. However, direct request logs to jpg files are not collected.

```
location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
    expires    +60d;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`access_log`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html#access_log) within the `location` block:

```
location ~ \.jpg$ {
  access_log /var/log/nginx/...;
}
```